# Is there any way to get current Twitter logged-in user already follow or unfollow me?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I need to get current Twitter logged-in user follow / unfollow me. Is this possible?

Note: I don't want to forward user to Twitter site, I want to know status on my own site.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to test whether the current user follows you or not? Or that you want to update the current user's Twitter account to _make_ them follow you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go Google and search "check twitter status js embed" and you will find the answer. The website http://www.sitepor500.com.br uses a plugin that does that too.

Answer (score 0):

Forward the user to the twitter site, and let them decide if they want to follow/unfollow you.

Comment: No , i did't want to forward to twiiter site ..
I want to know status on my own site..